# How do I activate a local caching nameserver?

Tags: bind, resolv.conf

I want to have strong DNS cache server on my local host (server). So I need to change name server to my localhost.

1. How can I change it?
   byt this config it seems I must don't change it via editor so how can I change it?

   ```
   root@asqar# cat /etc/resolv.conf 
   # Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
   #     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
   nameserver 4.2.2.4
   search asqar.net
   ```
2. I'm using `bind9` how can I set the DNS cache, any configure ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want a DNS cache on your local machine, use dnsmasq, not BIND.

Unless you really need a local iterative nameserver, de-install BIND.

```
sudo apt-get purge bind9
```

Now for dnsmasq. There are two ways of using dnsmasq.

1: If you are using NetworkManager to manage networking then you already have the dnsmasq-base package installed; you just have to enable the NetworkManager-controlled dnsmasq instance by editing `NetworkManager.conf`

```
sudo gedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

and ensuring that the line

```
dns=dnsmasq
```

is present. Next enable caching in this dnsmasq instance. Create a new configuration file called, e.g., `local`

```
sudo gedit /etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/local
```

and add the single line

```
cache-size=150
```

to change the default cache size from zero. Then restart network-manager

```
sudo restart network-manager
```

which will also start or restart the NetworkManager-controlled dnsmasq instance using the new nonzero cache size.

*This only works in Ubuntu 12.10 or later. In Ubuntu 12.04 the NetworkManager-controlled dnsmasq configuration cannot be customized and the cache size is zero.*

2: The other way of using dnsmasq is to run it as a server. To do this, install the `dnsmasq` package and configure it by editing `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` and setting `cache-size` to a value greater than zero.

In Ubuntu 12.10 the dnsmasq server will forward queries to external nameservers if the NetworkManager-controlled dnsmasq instance is disabled and will forward queries to the NetworkManager-controlled dnsmasq instance at the address 127.0.1.1 if the NetworkManager-controlled dnsmasq instance is enabled.

In Ubuntu 12.04 the same thing can be achieved but some additional manual configuration steps are required because in Ubuntu 12.04 the NetworkManager-controlled dnsmasq instance listens at 127.0.0.1 which conflicts with dnsmasq server in its default configuration.

Answer (score 2):

this may be helpful, I don't think it will work as is on ubuntu but you should be able to adapt it easily.

> > A simple named.conf which forwards all DNS queries to another
> >     nameserver, and caches the answers for possible reuse. Tested under
> >     OpenBSD 4.7 BETA with
>
> ```
> $ named -v
> BIND 9.4.2-P2
> ```
>
> > This type of configuration is useful to minimize the repeating
> >     nameserver queries issued when surfing the web. Not only for your
> >     notebook or laptop using wireless connections, but also for a
> >     department that wishes to make use of a LAN/WAN link efficiently.
> >
> > ```
> > The Access Control List (acl) limits useage of this forward-only nameserver to my local 192.168.222.0/24 subnet.
> > The queries are forwarded to a dnscache namerver running on my OpenBSD firewall at 192.168.222.10.
> > The cache size is limited to two MB, which probably is too much for a notebook or laptop. The comments show how to calculate this
> > ```
> >
> > amount in bytes using bc(1), the unlimited precision calculator.
>
> // Caching and forward only configuration
>
> ```
> // Access Control List
>
> acl  clients    {
>     192.168.222.0/24  ;
> };
>
> options {
>     forward only ;
>     forwarders { 192.168.222.10 ; } ; 
>     allow-query { clients ; } ;
>     // max-cache-size is in bytes : echo '2 * 1024^2' | bc
>     max-cache-size 2097152 ; 
>     empty-zones-enable yes;
> } ;
>
> # After editing this file please use 'named-checkconf' to validate!
> ```
>
> > To enable this under OpenBSD, assuming the above configuration has
> >     been saved as /var/naned/etc/caching-forward-only.conf, you have to
> >     add the following to /etc/rc.conf.local:
>
> ```
> named_flags='-4 -c /etc/caching-forward-only.conf'
> ```
>
> > Note that applications use the /etc/resolv.conf to find out which name
> >     server they should use. So for a departmental nameserver, all clients
> >     should have the iP address of that name server in /etc/resolv.conf
> >
> > For my small department in the garage, the clients have the following
> >     in /etc/resolv.conf
>
> ```
> nameserver 192.168.222.25
> ```

reference : http://www.daemonforums.org/showthread.php?t=4471

or try this, seems more Ubuntu-centered : http://soledadpenades.com/articles/ubuntu/using-bind-as-a-local-caching-name-server/